# Create objects with nested serializer by using the UUID

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a serializer like this:

```
class SureveyResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    respondent_profile = RespondentsProfileSerializer(read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
            ... some stuff ...
        return survey_response

    class Meta:
        model = SurveyResponse
        fields = '__all__'
```

My problem here is dealing with creating and reading objects using **the same serializer**. For reading, I want to show the nested instance of `respondent_profile` with all its fields.

For a `SurveyResponse` (and adding a relation to an existing respondent_profile) I want to simply pass the `UUID` of an existing `respondent_profile`.

Is this possible or do I need two different serializers?

Comment: I would suggest using get_respondent_profile(self, obj) method for serializing extra field in response.

Comment: Hm, serializerMethodFields are read_only by design so same behavior on writing. The serializer will not default to fall back on the pk for writing. Changing the name of the field would lead by adding an 'extra field' would lead to an inconsistent API

Comment: i think problem statement is not clear. do you want to use same serializer for creating and retrieving objects? is that so??

Comment: Hm, the exact answer to your question is even highlighted in my OP.